# C# LINQ performance when extension method called inside where clause

Tags: c#, performance, linq

I have a LINQ query like this

```
public static bool CheckIdExists(int searchId)
{
   return itemCollection.Any(item => item.Id.Equals(searchId.ConvertToString()));
}
```

`item.Id` is a `string` while `searchId` is an `int`. `.ConvertToString()` is an extension which which converts `int` to `string`

Code for ConvertToString:

```
public static string ConvertToString(this object input)
{
   return Convert.ToString(input, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}
```

Now my query is, **does `searchId.ConvertToString()` gets executed for each item in `itemCollection`?**

**Is computing `searchId.ConvertToString()` beforehand and calling the method like below improves performance?**

```
public static bool CheckIdExists(int searchId)
{
   string sId=searchId.ConvertToString();
   return itemCollection.Any(item => item.Id.Equals(sId));
}
```

**How to debug these two scenarios and observe their performances?**

Comment: "How to debug these two scenarios" - well, put `Console.WriteLine("I'm called!")` inside `ConvertToString` and observe how often its called in your scenarios.

Comment: @evk is being honest, the other thing is to put a stopwatch on it and time it..

Comment: will try the `Console.WriteLine` approach

Comment: or just set a breakpoint in the ConvertToString method and see how many times it is reached. Basic debugging

Comment: @RaduUngureanu I had tried it and it goes everytime inside the ConvertToSTring.. But thought without debugging it would work differently.. iknow.. silly assumption

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I re-generated the scenarios you talked about in your question. I tried following code and got this output.

But this is how you can debug this.

```
static List<string> itemCollection = new List<string>();

static void Main(string[] args)
{

    for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
    {
        itemCollection.Add(i.ToString());
    }

    var watch = new Stopwatch();
    watch.Start();

    Console.WriteLine(CheckIdExists(580748));
    watch.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine($"Took {watch.ElapsedMilliseconds}");

    var watch1 = new Stopwatch();
    watch1.Start();

    Console.WriteLine(CheckIdExists1(580748));
    watch1.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine($"Took {watch1.ElapsedMilliseconds}");

    Console.ReadLine();
}

public static bool CheckIdExists(int searchId)
{
    return itemCollection.Any(item => item.Equals(ConvertToString(searchId)));
}

public static bool CheckIdExists1(int searchId)
{
    string sId =ConvertToString(searchId);

    return itemCollection.Any(item => item.Equals(sId));
}

public static string ConvertToString(int input)
{
    return Convert.ToString(input, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
True
Took 170
True
Took 11
```

Comment: I tried writing based on  Rob's answer and ended up with your code... It looks like computing beforehand gives better performance

Comment: You can change integer numbers to generate different result. For large number, first method will take a long

Answer (score 1):

How long it takes is the ultimate guide. You can create a stopwatch to log the performance of any code. Just use the ElapsedMilliseconds to see how long has been taken. For very short operations I suggest using very long loops to get a more accurate length of time.

```
var watch = new Stopwatch();
watch.Start();
/// CODE HERE (IDEALLY IN A LONG LOOP)
Debub.WriteLine($"Took {watch.ElapsedMilliseconds}");
```

Comment: does getting ElapsedMilliseconds stop the stopwatch?

Comment: watch.Stop() does that. The watch is still ticking when you call ElapsedMilliseconds I believe.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it should be faster to get the string once. But I guess that compiler does optimize that thing for you (I just suspect this, don't ave anything to back it up. I just remeber that compilers are very good at detecting things that are not changing).

And no, it's not computed for every item, since LINQ method Any does not necessarily check all items. It return true for the first matching item. The only scenario when it checks all items, is where for none the lambda returns true.

If you want to test the speed difference,make sure to have more data - otherwise the difference may be too small.

Just do:

`itemCollection = Enumerable.Range(0, 1000).SelectMany(x => itemCollection).ToList() // or array or whatever the type of collection you have`

Than measure the times with StopWatch, just like @RobSedgwick said

Answer (score 0):

I think you have two solution:

1- make log and meke inside this log datetime.now
2- you can use the diagnostic Tools tab

hopefully this help you